# Why my Apple Watch complication real machine test displays strange images?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, widget, apple-watch-complication

[image]There is my code:

```
struct WidgetView: View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var widgetFamily
    var body: some View {
        switch widgetFamily {
            case .accessoryCorner:
            //Text("test")
            Text(entry.configuration.afterClassTime)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .padding()
                .lineLimit(1)
                .truncationMode(.tail)
                .widgetLabel {
                    Text(entry.configuration.nextclass)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .padding()
            }
            
            default:
            Text(entry.configuration.afterClassTime)
                .widgetLabel {
                    Text(entry.configuration.nextclass)
                        .font(.system(size: 13))
                }
        }
    }
}
```

It works without any issues on the simulator and displays the text I expected

But once I use my apple watch se real device to test, an image like this will be displayed(lower left corner)

I searched many docs and some passage, no anyone can help me. Thank you for your help.

I tried asking in the Apple Genius Bar, but there was no response to what I needed, and no one on the Apple forum responded.

I want to real device to test can show the same content with simulator

Comment: There is no image in your question. You should [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.